# Oracle Apex: Help Text Option for Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I love how you can set either inline or standard help text on page items. Unfortunately the only current region in APEX (Universal theme) that supports this functionality out of the box is new interactive grid.

But even here it is not ideal as it sits under Actions menu -> Help and contains additional text about IG functionalities which might be not what you want to show anyway.

Does anyone know of a work around in which I can set help text on an interactive report?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found another way that better represents what I wanted to display to my users. If you create a display only text field above your interactive report with the appearance template = Optional - Above. Then add this inline CSS to your page:

```
label[for="PX_YOUR_PAGE_ITEM"], #PX_YOUR_PAGE_ITEM {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
    }
```

The page item will now display as the region header (Display Only Form Field). Now you just add your help text and now you have a pretty, functional, region header with help text attached. (Sorry I can't embed images into my answer yet so plz up vote if you found this solution helpful).

*Note: In the images I have two region titles that can display help text. You must have a CSS block for each region title.

[Display Only Form Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOOE7.png)

[Help Text Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baynp.png)

Answer (score 4):

Just *set it* in column's property palette (left screenshot). Then run the report, click column's header (1), click the question mark (2) and - here's your help (3):

[image]

Comment: Always so helpful, thanks @Littlefoot